# How to nest $type inside $in operator in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

Mongo Document sample i am working on :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d07c59b0e914801ae05eb40"),       
    "tomato" : {               
            "rating" : 9,
            "reviews" : 54,
            "fresh" : 53,              

    }
```

}

I need a query to find documents with tomato.rating with $type either "string" or "int"
Basically i want to nest $type inside $in operator

How do we do that? Any idea would help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Example:
if your  collection name `vegetables`:

```
db.vegetables.find(
   { "tomato.rating" : { $type : [ "string" , "int" ] } }
)
```

Comment: @Nilotpal Did you try it?